# What Dog breed is my puppy?

Tags: dogs

[![I am just wondering.is this an American pit bull puppy or not?][1]][1]

Comment: breed identification are off topic here as an answer to this will often be opinion based,the only way to be 100% sure about the breed is to take a DNA test.when you gain reputation you can ask this question in chat to get an opinion about  what the breed might be.

Comment: https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, I assume there was a photo to be included in your question but it didn't work as it seems. One needs to have at least 20 reputation to write in chat; but if you could please edit and try including the photo again, then I could ask for you in the chat.